# Strapi: How to copy API between projects?

Tags: mongodb, strapi

If I copy an API/content type from one Strapi project to another it works, but if I try to add another Content type I get an error.

I use MongoDB. I used mongodump/mongorestore to get transfer the data. The databases are named the same.

Error message: "an error has occured"

The new content type is listed under CONTENT TYPES on the navigation bar, but not within content type builder.

What is the correct way to copy an api?

---

Detailed description:
Computer 1: Startet new strapi project with "strapi new". Choose Mongodb. Added content types after "strapi start". Created content types and data. Testet and used together with react. Mongodumped db. Uploaded project to private git repository. Git ignored node_modules folder.

Computer 2: Cloned git repository to another computer where I also use strapi. Yarn to install dependencies. Yarn is uptodate. Startet strapi successfully. Needed to add new username/password. Same as used on the other computer. The content of the content types were empty. Mongorestore to db. Content types now have the same data as in computer 1. Needed to set roles & permission because that was not transferred. Testet together with react. Tried to add a new content type thru content type builder. First noticed in green something like "content type saved successfully". Normally this takes longer. Reloaded page and error occured.

Comment: Hello, can you give us exact step you did to have this issue please.

Comment: Of course, I would love to. Added a detailed description in the question.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the Strapi version you use

Comment: @JimLAURIE it is 3.0.0-alpha.17. If I stop Strapi, use generate:api to generate a different api, then restarted it worked. This procedure with stopping and startet I have used a few times after errors have occured.

Comment: Okay did you start your app with `npm start` or `strapi start` ?

Comment: @JimLAURIE With strapi start